# Python Virtual Environment - cannot open shared file

Tags: python, environment

I have just started learning python and I am having issues to create a virtual environment. With virtualenv, I am getting the following error:

```
New python executable in /home/charles/Desktop/test/test/bin/python
/home/charles/Desktop/test/test/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: The executable /home/charles/Desktop/test/test/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/charles/Desktop/test' (should be '/home/charles/Desktop/test/test')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

With "venv" and I got the following error:

```
Error: Command '['/home/charles/Toto/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I am using python 3.6.1 and the zsh shell with Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit (gnome).

Comment: Have you installed the python-devel package ?

Comment: Please see [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) documentation which includes many details including [installation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/).